# Output numbers in exponential notation with a predefined exponent

Tags: matlab, printf, exponential, notation, format-specifiers

I have a set of integer values, for example:

```
V = [26767559, 6022443, 9923637]; % etc.
```

For my application, it is convenient to represent them as `<rounded_mantissa>E5` (that is, *some_val**10<sup>5</sup>), so for the above examples I want to get:

```
N = ["268E5", "60E5", "99E5"]; % I won't mind if it's E+05
```

At the moment, I'm using one of several conceivable workarounds to achieve this output,

```
N = round(V*1E-5) + "E5";
```

but I'd like to know if it's possible to specify the `formatSpec` of `sprintf`, `num2str` (etc.) such that it would output numbers with a specific value for the exponent (in this case, `5`), without performing division (like in `num2str(round(V/1E5).','%3uE5')`).

I'm using R2018a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least remove the use of `round`, then I don't think there's any further short-hand because it's just a single division...

```
N = num2str( V/1e5, '%.0fE5' )
```

The `.0` precision operator will force the 0 decimal place rounding for you anyway.

You can only specify the number of *digits* (significant or after the decimal point) using the `formatSpec` property, so unless you've got fixed numbers of digits (which you don't) you won't be able to use that alone.

Comment: Thanks for the code-golfing tip :) Accepting because of your indisputable last paragraph.